# I am trying to do a massive PostgreSQL update and can not figure out the proper way

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.1

```
    UPDATE member_copy
SET locked_date = CURRENT_DATE,
 notes = (
    SELECT
        notes
    FROM
        member_copy
    WHERE
        ID = 17579
) || ' CLOSED'
WHERE
    ID = 17579
```

I am trying to run a database update just like this in PostgreSQL 8.1.23. I need to do this update with about 800 ids at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should plan for an upgrade to a supported version *now*. 8.1 has been out of maintenance for years now.

Comment: I would love to, but that isn't my call.

Comment: Surely you can at least call out the potential for security issues that may arise from not doing so. Perhaps I've been privileged, but I've yet to meet a manager who sweeps that kind of problem under a rug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can largely simplify to:

```
UPDATE member_copy
SET locked_date = CURRENT_DATE
   ,notes = COALESCE(notes || ' ', '') || 'CLOSED'
WHERE id IN (17579, 12345, ...); --- 800 IDs
```

[`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is meant to catch cases where `notes IS NULL`.
Should even work in ancient Postgres 8.1. But you really must upgrade to a current version.

In modern day Postgres I would use a temp table of IDs (or a subselect) and join to it in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for me. Unfortunately upgrading isn't my call, but there is a new site planned for soon.